# How is this crontab interpreted "*/N * * * *" where N is between 31 and 59?

Tags: cron

If I need to run jobs exactly every 50 minutes, example.

```
00:50 run 1
01:40 run 2
02:30 run 3
03:20 run 4
04:10 run 5
05:00 run 6
06:50 run 7
```

Will `*/50 * * * *` cron work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

*/X means every X minute of the hour. Depending on the minute you set, it runs every minute or not. For example */5, every 5 minutes. */35 every 35th minute of the hour. If hours were 70 minutes long, */35 would run every 70 minutes. I hope this answer is not traumatizing Gilles.